# AsyncTask not showing URI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have tried everything all day. I want different buttons to work when I click them. I was doing so by using AsyncTasks.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mudd.devin.drive_now;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                new Action().execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Action.java

```
package com.mudd.devin.drive_now;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Devin on 4/9/2016.
 */
public class Action extends AsyncTask<URI, URI, Intent> {




    @Override
    protected Intent doInBackground(URI... params) {
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        return intent;
    }


}
```

Thank you in advance. Today I realized that I am a really shitty developer and apps are really hard to make.

Comment: Are you actually doing anything in `onPostExecute(Intent result)` - have you overridden this method in your `Action` `AsyncTask` to do something with the intent? Also have a look at this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#overview P.S. Don't be too hard on yourself!

Comment: I wasn't doing anything in onPostExecute. I was only touching doInBackground. I know that the Google Maps code works because I've used it before.

Comment: Well you need to override this method in order to do something with the intent.  If you're using Android Studio make sure your cursor in somewhere in your Action class, go up to the 'Code' menu, select "Override Methods" and select `onPostExecute()` - this will show the new method you've "overidden" now you can do whatever with the result object (intent) like `startActivity(intent). To be honest, for what you're doing you don't need an AsyncTask for this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't get why you want an asynctask just to launch another process with an intent. AyncTask are useful for intense process like network operations or filereading, but using it for creation of intent is real waste!

And I can't see you pass any URI parameters to the AsyncTask.!

So you can call the intent directly from onclick(which I would recommend). Or you should start the activity from somewhere like these:

Method 1

---

```
public class Action extends AsyncTask<URI, Void, Intent> {
    private final Context context;
    public Action(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Intent doInBackground(URI... params) {
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent){
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
new Action(context).execute();
```

Method 2:

---

```
public class Action extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>{  private final Context context;
    public Action(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Intent doInBackground(Void params) {
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        context.startActivity(intent)


  return null;
 }
}
```

## Recommended Method

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
             Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(intent)
            }
        });
```

And I don't recommend you using Action as a class name!

Comment: This is exactly how I did it earlier. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `onPostExecute` to your `AsyncTask`. If you don't, your result (the intent) will be just discarded.

E.g.

```
public class Action extends AsyncTask<URI, Void, Intent> {
    private final Context context;
    public Action(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Intent doInBackground(URI... params) {
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent){
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```